# Can I roller-skate on bike paths in USA?

Tags: usa

This question is sort of an extension of the question [Is it safe to roller-skate on sidewalks in USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47787/is-it-safe-to-roller-skate-on-sidewalks-in-usa).

If there are designated bike lanes in a city (say, Chicago and New York to prevent it from being broad), can I assume that its OK to skate (inline) on those too?

Comment: If no one knows here, you might try bicycles.stackexchange

Comment: This depends on the local ordinance, and so will vary by state, municipality, and possibly by neighborhood or street.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to roller-skate on sidewalks in USA?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47787/is-it-safe-to-roller-skate-on-sidewalks-in-usa)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least in New York City.  Note the sign in this image that directs walkers and runners to the walkway, and skaters and cyclists to the bikeway:

[image: From the Wikipedia article "Manhattan Waterfront Greenway"]